# How to collapse the jquery nestable tree by default

Tags: jquery, treeview

I am using jquey.nestable plugin to render tree. Now on page load the tree was in expanded view by default. I want to collapse it on page load. How to do this?

https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to collapse all items use:

```
$(selector).nestable('collapseAll');
```

You have to use that command after creating your `Nestable`. For example:

```
$('#nestable').nestable({});
$('#nestable').nestable('collapseAll');
```